# How would this script work in Ubuntu?

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

I start learning Bash Scripting by using this guide: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/abs-guide.pdf

However I got stuck at first script:

```
cd /var/log
cat /dev/null > messages
cat /dev/null > wtmp
echo "Log files cleaned up."
```

What does line 2 & 3 do in Ubuntu (I understand cat)? Is it only for other linux distributions? After running this script as root, output I get is Logs file cleaned up. But /var/log still contains all the files.

Comment: The files are not gone, but _their contents are_.  `ls -l /var/log` and you should see 0 bytes as the size of those two logs.

Comment: `cat /dev/null` reads from the pseudofile bitbucket and writes it to the log file via `>` output redirection, leaving them empty. This isn't specific to any distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/dev/null` is a special file, which can be used to redirect output you don't want.

As for reading it, that is `cat /dev/null`, it simply print nothing because it's like an empty file.

Since `>` is an operator which redirect the standard output to a file (here `messages` and `wtmp`), you'll see that:

- `/var/log/messages` and `/var/log/wtmp` will now exists if there were not here
- their size would be 0 bytes.

Comment: Actually the most important (and dangerous if you don't know it) thing about those two lines is that they will **truncate** the file if it exists.